# Error 500 issue - Trying to create basic stripe checkout payment gateway

Tags: php, stripe-payments, checkout

I tried to implement a simple stripe gateway on a live site but for some reason I get the following message after the stripe checkout details are filled out and the submit button is clicked and it directs to charge.php and I have no idea where I am going wrong

"The ... page isn’t working

... is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

**index.php stripe code**

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="*Edited for question*"
        data-amount="1499"
        data-name="*Edited for question*"
        data-description="2 widgets"
        data-image="*Edited for question*"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-currency="eur">
    </script>
</form>
```

**charge.php code**

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

try {

    Stripe_Charge::create([
        "amount" => 1499,
        "currency" => "eur",
        "card" => $token,
        "description" => "Charge"
        ]);

} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
    //do something with error here
}

header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

?>
```

**Init.php code**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$stripe = [
'publishable' => '*Edited for question*',
'private' => '*Edited for question*'
];

Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['private']);
?>
```

Comment: Error 500 indicates an server error or script error. Have you checked the error_log? And which version of php are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Stripe requires you to have the following php libraries:

- curl
- json
- mbstring

Make sure you have all of them with "*php -m*" before tracking down other solutions.